# Show text boxes depending on drop down box selection

Tags: c#, textbox, dropdownbox

I want to show multiple text boxes depending on the number a user selects from a dropdown box. Example below:

[image]

So whatever number is selected in the drop down the page refreshes and displays that number of text boxes. I need to go up to 20 fields. Is there a way to do this in C#, or maybe with the Ajax Control Toolkit?

ASPX

```
<asp:Label ID="NumAccounts" runat="server" Text="# of Accounts"></asp:Label>      <asp:DropDownList
        ID="EmpNameList" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="NumAccountsList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoPostBack="True">
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Try looking [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1785209.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:Label ID="NumAccounts" runat="server" Text="# of Accounts"></asp:Label>      <asp:DropDownList
            ID="EmpNameList" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="NumAccountsList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="True">
             </asp:DropDownList>

     <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
        </div>



protected void NumAccountsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
              ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
               for(i=0; i<Convert.ToInt32(EmpNameList.SelectedItem.Value); i++)
                  {

                               TextBox tx= new TextBox();
                               tx.ID="tx"+i;
                               ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
                               ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                  }

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting "ContentPlaceHolder can only be used in .master files." when I attempt to run this.

Comment: sorry should be just placeholder

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much, one quick question, right now it just puts all the text boxes on one line, if I wanted to put them on different lines using line breaks where would I place the <br />?

Answer (score 1):

sure there is.
use:

```
int ctrlCount=Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
int ctrlTopPos=30;

lbl_name.Text="Name:";
for(int i=0;i<ctrlCount;i++)
{
Label lbl_name=new Label();
TextBox txt_cur=new TextBox();
txt_cur.Top=ctrlTopPos+(i*30);
lbl_name.top=ctrlTopPos+(i*30);
txt_cur.left=lbl_name.Width+30;
Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl_name);
Panel1.Controls.Add(txt_cur);
}
```

Create an asp:panel and name it Panel1.
Put the given code inside the SelectedIndexChanged event of your dropdownlist.
set the autopostback property of your dropdownlist to true.
it will work.
hope that helps.